# JAXB Adapters and what happens on the other end in .NET?

Tags: .net, jaxb

I've created a rather large heap of JAXB adapters to deal with immutable classes. It all works fine when both ends use the annotated Java classes.

Looking at the resulting schema from CXF java2ws tool, I can see that the .NET result of consuming this stuff, or even the java equivalent of someone feels compelled to run ws2java for themselves, will expose all the adaptive classes. I suppose that in Java-land I could supply a collection of JAX-B customization XML to help someone pretty-up the output, but what can I do for a .NET consumer to result in an API of nice immutable objects and hidden over-the-wire adapters?

Comment: The question is a little misleading.  Is the real issue how to achieve an immutable object model in .Net?  With a possible solution resembling how this can be done in JAXB with adapters?

Comment: The question is how to create an immutable object model in .NET by consuming XML schema from JAXB when using the usual JAX-B stuff to deal with immutables.

Comment: Not sure JAXB adapters make this hard.  Here is my take on JAXB and immutable objects:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html

Comment: @Blaise: I'm very familiar with your Java stuff, I made good use of it. Its the .NET side I'm poking at.